Man pranks town from jail
I watched a movie a couple of years back, it was about a man and his best friend they went out for a swim in like a local lake and one of them drowns (they weren't kids, they were drunk), he was the sheriffs son. 
A few years later he is put in an overnight cell, he continues to escape to "prank" the town and then returns to the cell before the sheriff realizes he is gone.
(He escapes and breaks a window, steals a car, and throws a can of paint over a phoneline)
It's an English language movie probably happens in the US and probably US made.
The movie was released sometime before 2000? 
Main characters are a police officer or the sheriff, the guy in the overnight cell that his best friend drowned and an old man that has to fix broken windows.

Can you remember what language it is? Where it was released? What genre?

it's an english movie probably happens in the US i belive, and Rlease there, but not sure what the genre would be, and yes you got that right. except they werent kids they were drunk and decided to go swiming in the lake his best friend drowns, the sherif was the guys dad and blames him for his death. after a couple of years something happens and he is put in a cell for the night, he keeps escaping and broke into like a conveniance store and stole paint and some stuff. Sorry english isn't my main language

yea, lol sorry. "prank" is like the best word i can find for this. He escapes and breaks a window, steals a car, and throws a can of paint over a phoneline that's all i remember and i've been searching for this movie for about 40 minutes when i found this website.

I found it!!! It's called Reach the Rock

Two school kids Robin and Danny who are best friends are drinking on the side of a river. Robin bets the other that he can't swim across the river and "Reach The Rock". Danny takes the bet and drowns halfway towards the rock. The entire town blames Robin for his friend's death, he runs away never to be seen again. He eventually comes back to his home town of Shermerville and goes crazy, and starts to trash the town (i.e. breaking store-front windows, stealing a police car). He also meets up with his old high school girlfriend. The majority of the movie takes place in one night.

